# How to fix npm audit fix issues?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, lodash

```
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ lodash                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.17.5                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ react-native-cached-image                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ react-native-cached-image > lodash                           │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/577                             │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
found 11 vulnerabilities (2 low, 8 moderate, 1 high) in 26316 scanned packages
  11 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
```

This shows up when I try to `npm install`, and all of them required manual review. I've tried to visit [this](https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/577) to check for more info and apparently it's because my `lodash` is of version `4.17.4`. So I've then run `npm install --save lodash@4.17.5` and checked my `package.json` to make sure it's reflecting correctly.

However, it seems the vulnerabilities is still there. Wondering if I fix it the wrong way?

As per requested, the body of package.json

```
"dependencies": {
   "lodash": "^4.17.5",
}
```

Comment: in your `package.json` what do you have for `lodash` in dependencies? Post the actual string in the question body please.

Comment: @Akrion: Yes it does have

Comment: Wait ... it talks about the `react-native-cached-image` that lib has that issue since it probably has dependency on that older  version of lodash no? Can you see in that lib what does it say in its `package.json`?

Comment: Yep in that lib you have `4.17.4` just checked in their github @ https://github.com/kfiroo/react-native-cached-image/blob/master/package.json#L51

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can solve it with https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions

1) add resolutions section

```
"resolutions": {
  "lodash": "^4.17.5"
}
```

2) run

```
rm -r node_modules
npx npm-force-resolutions
npm install
```

Answer (score 10):

Issue is related to the `react-native-cached-image` package having a dependency on lodash `4.17.4` as you can see here: https://github.com/kfiroo/react-native-cached-image/blob/master/package.json#L51

Comment: In that case I can only wait until the package owner to update the dependency on their own? Or for the local version I can work something about it?

Comment: Possible to navigate into the node_module and doing an npm update on this package?

Comment: Their latest version is `v1.4.3`. If you are on that version then you can either wait (and maybe open an issue on their repo to address this) or you could also `fork` their repo and make the change yourself. See if that fixes it. This way at least you know for sure what is the problem and what the solution.

Comment: If you fork and change it ... if there are no side-effects/bugs you can push a PR and see if they accept it etc.

Comment: Any luck? Ware you able to prove that changing the lodash version in that package fixes the issue?